# Delete Ubuntu & allocate space back to Windows?

Tags: windows, lubuntu, uninstall, uefi

So after fighting with Ubuntu, Microsoft Windows and UEFI for far too long, my patience has finally run out...

[I have been unable to get everything working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418150/computer-hangs-on-boot-logo-when-using-power-button), and thus the kids exclusively use Windows 8.1 on this computer... So I want want to remove Ubuntu entirely.

But short of a (Windows 8.1) clean install, what is the easiest way to:
* Completely remove Ubuntu;
* Allocate the space back to Windows 8.1 and;
* Undo any changes to my UEFI/restore my UEFI back to its factory state (if required or recommended)?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys!

I thought this was the process... But thought I'd better check so I don't screw things up - I've never seen the need to uninstall Ubuntu on my computers (this is the kid's).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If installed via Windows Installer, you can simply select Ubuntu from your programs list and choose uninstall.

From there, it is quite simple to re-allocate the data back to Windows 8.1.

You can do this by opening Start and typing Disk Management. You will see an option along the lines of manage disk partitions.

This program will allow you to select and allocate un-allocated data.

Simply right click Drive C (or whichever drive volume you wish to assign the un-allocated data to) and click Extend Volume, where you will follow the instructions given by the confirmation window.

However, if you did not install Ubuntu via WUBI, then you will still be using Disk Management program.

The process is similar: Simply select the drive volume labeled Ubuntu or something similar and delete the volume. Then follow the above steps to allocate the newly un-allocated data to a usable volume.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sorry that you have problems with ubuntu. To remove it entirely and use the space in windows, boot with windows (I do not know which win you are using ), under control panel, administrative tools, find disk manager (name may be smt different). Find the partitions you have installed ubuntu. Format them to ntfs and set it as a windows drive by giving it drive letter. To restore your UEFI please follow this link [How to fix the MBR for Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326532/how-to-fix-the-mbr-for-windows-7)